add_rewrite_rules triggered through init, but error happens in WP's rewrite.php
I have a simple plugin that I'm working on, and in the init action I'm using add_rewrite_rules, but I get a fatal error "Call to a member function add_rule() on null in wp-includes/rewrite.php:143".
My code:
add_action( 'init', [ __CLASS__, 'addRules' ]);

public static function addRules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-acct(/.*)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=my-acct',
        'top'
    );
}

If I add the following at the top of the method, the error goes away:
if( ! is_object( $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'] ) )
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'] = new \WP_Rewrite();

I'm just wondering why I don't see other plugins do this? What am I doing wrong?

the wp rewrite object is created before the call of the init action (see in wp-settings.php here) then I don't undersand your result. edit your question to show a complete plugin code which throw this error.

Yes, the problem was that in another part of the plugin I was calling the static method addRules, and it happening outside of any hook. Once I fixed that, all is well.
